# How to send batch notifications in GCM using PushSharp

Tags: c#, android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, pushsharp

As the title says, I have a list of all my registration IDs, and I want to send the same message to all of them at once.

I was told that GCM can handle approximately 1000 notifications at once, but I'm really confused as to how to do this in `PushSharp` (other than actually sending them individually, using a for loop). If anyone is familiar with this I would really appreciate some assistance.

He's some generic code

```
push.RegisterGcmService(new GcmPushChannelSettings(ApiKey));

push.QueueNotification(new GcmNotification().ForDeviceRegistrationId(RegistrationID)
                                  .WithJson(json));
```

Instead of having 1 registration ID i'd like to send in a list of them. 
References to FAQ's but no actual answer on how to do so.

[Reference 1](https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp/issues/45)

[Reference 2](https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp/pull/152)

[Reference 3](https://github.com/antonvasilenko/PushSharp/commit/46b540c26f29772304d5a4cc44a9d4b110c14e03)

Comment: Thanks Sam for the edit!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never used Push Sharp, but [based on this code](https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp/blob/master/PushSharp.Android/Gcm/GcmFluentNotification.cs) :

You are currently using this method, which accepts a single Registration ID :

```
public static GcmNotification ForDeviceRegistrationId(this GcmNotification n, string deviceRegistrationId)
{
    n.RegistrationIds.Add(deviceRegistrationId);
    return n;
}
```

Use this method instead, which accepts multiple Registration IDs :

```
public static GcmNotification ForDeviceRegistrationId(this GcmNotification n, IEnumerable<string> deviceRegistrationIds)
{
    n.RegistrationIds.AddRange(deviceRegistrationIds);
    return n;
}
```

Comment: :) Thanks! I got it to work, I sent in a list of strings and it accepted it!

Comment: This methos send one message to batch devices. But how can I send batch notifications? Foe example: I have 20 different messages and 20 devices. How can I send push notification in batch ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use that using to get extended methods

```
using PushSharp;
using PushSharp.Android;
using PushSharp.Core;
```

Then you can use

```
GcmNotification notification = new GcmNotification().ForDeviceRegistrationId(pRegistrationIds)
                                              .WithJson(pMessage);
```