# How to send Batch Push Notification Android on C# .Net

Tags: c#, android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I have two methods for sending Push Notification
First example:

```
public void SendPushNotification(String regId, String message, String googleAppId, String senderId)
    {
        var value = message;
        var tRequest = WebRequest.Create(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RequestUrl"]);
        tRequest.Method = "post";
        tRequest.ContentType = " application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8";
        tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Authorization: key={0}", googleAppId));

        tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Sender: id={0}", senderId));

        string postData = "data.message=" + value + "&registration_id=" + regId + "";
        var byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
        tRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

        var dataStream = tRequest.GetRequestStream();
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        dataStream.Close();

        var tResponse = tRequest.GetResponse();

        dataStream = tResponse.GetResponseStream();

        if (dataStream != null)
        {
            var tReader = new StreamReader(dataStream);

            String sResponseFromServer = tReader.ReadToEnd();

            var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse) tResponse;
            string statusCode = httpResponse.StatusCode.ToString();

            tReader.Close();
        }
        if (dataStream != null) dataStream.Close();
        tResponse.Close();
    }
```

Second example. I use PushBroker from PushSharp

```
            var push = new PushBroker();
            push.RegisterGcmService(new GcmPushChannelSettings(apikey));
            push.QueueNotification(
                new GcmNotification().ForDeviceRegistrationId(deviceId).WithJson(json));
```

And this methods works good. 
I know how send batch push notification (i mean one message and song for a list of devices). I saw example there
 [How to send batch notifications in GCM using PushSharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17933125/how-to-send-batch-notifications-in-gcm-using-pushsharp?rq=1)

But I would like to send push notification in batch, where for every device i have some special message and some song name.  So did You know any solution for my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't send different messages to different Registration IDs in batch.

The JSON request that Google Cloud Messaging accepts supports a single payload (inside the `data` element) and 1 to 1000 Registration IDs. That means in each request you can either send one message to one Registration ID or the same message to multiple Registration IDs.